# Mysql logs only for one database

Tags: mysql, logging

Hot to configure mysql to log information, only for specific database or table?

For example i need to log authentification requests from Postfix to mysql.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [MySQL query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log) for this. It can only be activated for the whole MySQL server and not only a specific table or database but you can use the standard UNIX command line tools like `grep` to get the specific information you want out of the log file.

Comment: @joschi the log file doesn't log the database name on every line so I don't see a way to filter out entries for a specific database